# Windows sleep mode if display is disconnected

Tags: windows-10

I'm unsure of what is happening.

I have a PC with Windows 10 Pro that I use as server for a bot, which simulates clicks. As soon as the monitor is unplugged, a few minutes later seems to go into sleep mode or something similar and bot just stops working. If I check remotely through AnyDesk the bot starts to work normally again. If I close the session in AnyDesk a few minutes later bot stops working.

I set up the power plan in Windows as High Performance, both options of turn off the display and put the computer to sleep are in Never, I also checked advanced settings and all seems normal. Am I missing any other change?

Comment: What specifically is being done to simulate clicks?

Comment: the bot uses screen coordinates according to the resolution detected to change position and do left clicks